# No composite key property found for type error in Spring JPA2

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an error in spring JPA

org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property CompanyId found for type CompanyUserDetail!

```
@Embeddable
public class CompanyUserKey implements Serializable {

public CompanyUserKey() {
}

@Column(name = "company_id")
private UUID companyId;

@Column(name = "user_name")
private String userName;

public UUID getCompanyId() {
    return companyId;
}

public void setCompanyId(UUID companyId) {
    this.companyId = companyId;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "company_user_detail")
public class CompanyUserDetail {


@EmbeddedId
CompanyUserKey companyUserkey;

public CompanyUserKey getCompanyUserkey() {
    return companyUserkey;
}

public void setCompanyUserkey(CompanyUserKey companyUserkey) {
    this.companyUserkey = companyUserkey;
}
}
```

I am trying to access below method Service layer

```
@Component
public interface CompanyUserRepository extends JpaRepository<CompanyUserDetail, CompanyUserKey> {

public List<CompanyUserDetail> findByCompanyId(UUID companyId);
}
```

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Is spring generating the underlying implementation of your repository?  If so, I believe you might need to change your method signature to `findByCompanyUserKey` perhaps?

Comment: @Naros: I can change method to findByCompanyUserKey but that is not  required. I want the method to return  list of users for a companyId

Comment: Is this using spring-data-jpa's auto-generated implementations from an interface or are you writing the query yourself?  If the latter, please post the contents of `findByCompanyId` or show what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

Since in java model your `CompanyUserKey` is a property in the `CompanyUserDetail` class, I believe you should use full path (`companyUserkey.companyId`) to reach `companyId`:

```
public List<CompanyUserDetail> findByCompanyUserkeyCompanyId(UUID companyId);
```

Also note that you have a naming inconsistency: field in `CompanyUserDetail` is named `companyUserkey` instead of `companyUserKey`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not using `spring-data-jpa`'s auto generated implementations, your method contents might look something like the following:

```
FROM CompanyUserDetail c WHERE c.companyUserKey.companyId = :companyId
```

Now simply provide that query to the `EntityManager`

```
entityManager.createQuery( queryString, CompanyUserDetail.class )
             .setParameter( "companyId", companyId )
             .getResultList();
```

The key points are:

- Query uses a named bind parameter called *:companyId* (not the leading `:`).
- Parameter values are bound in a secondary step using `setParameter` method variants.
- `createQuery` uses a second argument to influence type safety so that the return value from `getResultList` is a `List<CompanyUserDetail>` just like you requested.

Looking at `spring-data-jpa`'s implementation however, I suspect it could look like this:

```
public interface CustomerUserRepository 
                 extends JpaRepository<CompanyUserDetail, CompanyUserKey> {
  @Query("select c FROM CompanyUserDetail c WHERE c.companyUserKey.companyId = :companyId")
  List<CompanyUserDetail> findByCompanyId(@Param("companyId") UUID companyId);
}
```